# Bitmap-render part of plot during vector-graphics export in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, vector-graphics, bitmapimage

I have a quite complex function that I plot using `fsurf` with a reasonably high `MeshDensity` (I cannot go much lower than the default, which is 35). Exporting this figure (`saveas(gcf, 'file.pdf', 'pdf');`) results in a 20-something MB pdf file of very nice quality, which nonetheless renders terribly slow. I would like to reduce the file size and, most importantly, the complexity of this pdf file, without exporting the whole plot (by which I mean the whole MATLAB figure) as a bitmap. How can I do that?

The perfect answer would explain how I can convert the surface plot (by which I mean, just the colored function surface on the white background) into a bitmap while maintaining the vectorized nature of axes and labels.

**Update**: Here's an example of such a plot.

[image]

Comment: "I want a vector and a bitmap, *at the same time*". Hmmmmmm.

Comment: @AnderBiguri in my world, this is called "embedding", and not a great source of confusion for anyone who has ever seen a photograph in a pdf file.

Comment: A photograph in a pdf file is just a bitmap, it has no vector graphics. Show your image, it may be possible, just may

Comment: @AnderBiguri well, standard text, unless rendered as a bitmap, too, is pretty close to what I consider vector graphics. So should I say, "anyone who has ever seen a photograph *next to some text* in a pdf file"? I am sure you have got my point anyway. I'll update the question with some snapshot.

Comment: No offence, but I don't get your point. You can not "consider" something vector graphics. Vector graphics is a way of storing the information, not a visual appearance. Something is, or is not vector graphics. You can put a bitmap in a PDF, without any problem. I dont think you can make a figure that is both bitmap (for the surf) and vector (for the axis). I don't think there is any file format that allows that.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Of course you can: in MATLAB, `imagesc(rand(100)),saveas(gcf,'plot.pdf')`. The result is a pdf file with a bitmap embedded with a set of vectorized axes. The *file format* (you mentioned that) is certainly not the limitation here.

Comment: I don't think the surf is a bitmap, I am convinced that either everything is saved as a hihg-res png or as a vectorized set of coordinates. That is why your complex data gets very big, because it is saved as vector. You can save an image as vector graphics, by defining a square of color X for each pixel. its not a bitmap if it looks like a bitmap, its a bitmap if its saved pixel by pixel

Comment: @AnderBiguri you may have finally gotten my point. It's not a bitmap, but I want it to be saved as a bitmap. Simple as that. I would not ask here if it was obvious, but I am sure there is a way. I may even have found a solution, which is only impeded by repeatedly having to comment here.

Comment: Apologies if I sound "agressive" I don't meant to. I still not get your point sorry. Is `getframe` then `imshow`/`imagesc` what you are looking for?

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, I am working a solution using `getframe`, which I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371252/matlab-render-graphical-objects-to-a-bitmap-in-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my function BitmapRender, which Bitmap-renders part of the figure:

```
%% Test Code
clc;clf;
Objects = surf(-4-2*peaks);
hold('on');
Objects(2 : 50) = plot(peaks);
Objects(51) = imagesc([20 40], [0, 5], magic(100));
hold('off');
ylim([0 10]);
zlim([-10 15]);
Objects(1).Parent.GridLineStyle = 'none';
view(45, 45);
set(gcf, 'Color', 'white');
rotate3d on

saveas(gcf, 'pre.pdf');
BitmapRender(gca, Objects(2 : 3 : end));
% BitmapRender(gca, Objects(2 : 3 : end), [0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5], false);
saveas(gcf, 'post.pdf');
```

The function itself is pretty simple, except for the (re-)handling of visibility, as pressing the space key (after rotating, zooming etc) re-renders the figure.

```
function BitmapRender(Axes, KeepObjects, RelativePosition, Draft, Key)

if nargin < 2
    KeepObjects = [];
end
if nargin < 3
    RelativePosition = [0 0 1 1];
end
if nargin < 4
    Draft = false;
end
if nargin < 5
    Key = '';
end

Figure = Axes.Parent;
FigureInnerWH = Figure.InnerPosition([3 4 3 4]);
PixelPosition = round(RelativePosition .* FigureInnerWH);

if isempty(Key)
    OverlayAxes = axes(Figure, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', PixelPosition ./ FigureInnerWH);
    if Draft
        OverlayAxes.Box = 'on';
        OverlayAxes.Color = 'none';
        OverlayAxes.XTick = [];
        OverlayAxes.YTick = [];
        OverlayAxes.HitTest = 'off';
    else
        uistack(OverlayAxes, 'bottom');
        OverlayAxes.Visible = 'off';
    end
    setappdata(Figure, 'BitmapRenderOriginalVisibility', get(Axes.Children, 'Visible'));

    Axes.CLimMode = 'manual';
    Axes.XLimMode = 'manual';
    Axes.YLimMode = 'manual';
    Axes.ZLimMode = 'manual';

    hManager = uigetmodemanager(Figure);
    [hManager.WindowListenerHandles.Enabled] = deal(false);
    set(Figure, 'KeyPressFcn', @(f, e) BitmapRender(gca, KeepObjects, RelativePosition, Draft, e.Key));
elseif strcmpi(Key, 'space')
    OverlayAxes = findobj(Figure, 'Tag', 'BitmapRenderOverlayAxes');
    delete(get(OverlayAxes, 'Children'));
    OriginalVisibility = getappdata(Figure, 'BitmapRenderOriginalVisibility');
    [Axes.Children.Visible] = deal(OriginalVisibility{:});
else
    return;
end

if Draft
    return;
end

Axes.Visible = 'off';

KeepObjectsVisibility = get(KeepObjects, 'Visible');
[KeepObjects.Visible] = deal('off');

drawnow;
Frame = getframe(Figure, PixelPosition);

[Axes.Children.Visible] = deal('off');
Axes.Visible = 'on';
Axes.Color = 'none';
if numel(KeepObjects) == 1
    KeepObjects.Visible = KeepObjectsVisibility;
else
    [KeepObjects.Visible] = deal(KeepObjectsVisibility{:});
end

Image = imagesc(OverlayAxes, Frame.cdata);
uistack(Image, 'bottom');
OverlayAxes.Tag = 'BitmapRenderOverlayAxes';
OverlayAxes.Visible = 'off';

end
```

Obviously, the solution is pixel-perfect in terms of screen pixels. Two pdf files (`pre` and `post`) look like this. Note that surface, image and some plot lines are bitmap rendered, but some other plot lines, as well as axes and labels are still vectorized.

[image]
[image]