# How can I rasterize surface plot while keeping axes as vector graphics in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure, vector-graphics, rasterizing

I am making a 3D surface plot in MATLAB, and I want to rasterize the surface plot (to save image size and loading speed) while keeping the rest of the figure (e.g., axes, labels, titles, etc.) as vector graphics. How can I do this? Right now I have the following:

```
x = linspace(-2, 2, 201);
y = linspace(-2, 2, 201);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = sin(sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2));

fig = figure;

colormap parula
surf(X, Y, Z, 'FaceColor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceLighting', 'gouraud')
daspect([4 4 1])
axis tight
view(-50, 30)
camlight left

exportgraphics(fig, 'test_matlab_02.pdf', 'ContentType', 'vector')
```

If I set `ContentType` to `vector`, then the whole figure is vector graphics. If I set `ContentType` to `image`, then the whole figure becomes rasterized. How can I have a rasterized surface plot with vector graphics for the remaining features in the figure?

Comment: Fundamentally, the image is going to be stored on disk in a vector or a bitmap file format, you would need an image format which supports both (do you know of one? I don't!), and then presumably a very custom way to write to it

Comment: Cuz in matplotlib it is as simple as setting `ax.plot_surf(...,rasterized=True)` and `fig.savefig('test.pdf', dpi=500)` then I can achieve what I want with `dpi` controlling the resolution of the rasterized surface plot. I just find MATLAB to give better quality surface plot in terms of the lighting and coloring so I wanna see if I can achieve the same thing (rasterized surface plot + remaining stuff in vector graphics) without too much hacking in MATLAB.

Comment: @Wolfie PDF, EPS and SVG all support both vector graphics and bitmaps. It is perfectly possible to combine both in one figure.

Comment: What @CrisLuengo says -- for PDF there is no need to abandon vectors. If you insist, someone wrote a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286749) for this on SO ages ago.

Comment: This is one of the main reasons I completely abandoned Matlab... The hoops you have to jump through to get consistent, high quality figures are just ridiculous for the details you really need.

Answer (score 4):

File Exchange offers [vecrast](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64650-vecrast), which might work in this case. It’s supposed to be able to combine rasterized and vector formats.

From the description of the `vecrast` function:

> vecrast is a function that allows to automatically save a figure with
> mixed vector and raster content. More specifically, two copies of the
> figure of interest are created, rasterFigure and vectorFigure. Patches,
> surfaces, contours, images, and lights are kept in rasterFigure but
> removed from vectorFigure. rasterFigure is then saved as a temporary
> .png image with the required resolution. The .png file is subsequently
> inserted into the vectorFigure, and the result is saved in a single
> vector file.

The function is able to handle both 2D and 3D plots, as specified in the notes:

> - The graphics smoothing (anti-aliasing) is turned off for the raster    figure. This improves sharpness at the borders of the image and at the
>   same time greatly reduces file size. You may change this option in the
>   script by setting 'GraphicsSmoothing', 'on' (line 97).
> - A resolution of no less than 300 dpi is advised. This ensures that    interpolation at the edges of the raster image does not cause the
>   image    to bleed outside the prescribed axis (make a test with 20dpi
>   on the    first example and you will see what I mean).
> - The stacking option has been introduced to accomodate 2D and 3D plots    which require the image behind or in front the axis,
>   respectively. This    difference can be seen in the examples below.
> - I strongly advise to take a look at the tightPlots function that allows    setting exact sizes of figures.